# How can I solve unauthorized error in angular?

Tags: angular, api, rest

I have a small challenge to work with API in Angular11.

I want to use the post method to create and add items to API and I have an unauthorized error in the browser.

What should I do?

Comment: Would you please be more verbose and describe better the error that you are getting.

Comment: Please add minimum replicable code so we could know what issue you are facing and what effor you did to solve it

Answer (score 0):

Either please attach the `headers` in your each and every API request.
Or a better way would be to create  `proxy.conf.json` file. This proxy file entry should be reflected under your `angular.json` and to execute need to change in  `package.json` file.
Below are the file changes example

**proxy.conf.json**

```
{
    "/api/*": {
    "target": "http://xxx.xx.2.19:8080/cda/",
    "secure": false,
    "logLevel": "debug",
    "changeOrigin": true
    },
}
```

**angular.json**

```
"architect": {
    "serve": {
        "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
         "options": {
         "browserTarget": "<application-name>:build",
         "proxyConfig": "src/proxy.conf.json" <-- HERE
        },
    },
```

**package.json**

```
ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json
```

**!!Caution:** These changes will only work on your local machine, where as when you deploy on server you need to handle it differently.

Answer (score -1):

It seems you haven't put authentication credentials on your api endpoint,

The HTTP **401 Unauthorized** client error status response code indicates that the request has not been applied because it lacks valid **authentication credentials** for the target resource. This status is sent with a WWW-Authenticate header that contains information on how to authorize correctly.

for more information visit [this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/401)